# Resize ViewController size in UIViewControllerContextTransitioning

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2, uiviewanimationtransition

I am using UIViewControllerContextTransitioning for custom transitions.
I have 2 view controllers , first view controller and second view controller.

I want to add secondview controller on firstview controller with animation. I have achieved it, and i can also see the first view controller below but i want the secondview contoller's size to be 80% of firstview controllers. so how do i resize UIViewContoller?

Please help, Thanks in advance.